# Accessing pipeline variables by name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

We have a particular scenario where we retrieve secrets from a Key Vault and use it in our release pipeline. This can be easily implemented with the "Azure Key Vault" tasks in Devops which will fetch them and store them as a pipeline variable.

So far so good, easy to do but we have a small issue. The customer insists that the secret's name includes the environment, meaning that we have different secret names depending on the environment (TEST/UAT/PROD/...)

Because we have one pipeline for all environments, we would like to be able to specify which secret to fetch via a pipeline variable, then get the secret and push it into another pipeline variable. We are still using classic pipelines, not YAML.

You can access pipeline variables in Powershell via the macro `$(variablename)`; is there any way how we can access it via a variable name? I tried several things like `Get-Variable` or `"$($(KeyVault.SecretName))"`, but none of those seem to work.

Anybody has another idea how I can achieve this?

Regards,
Sven

Comment: I think you need to repeat the "adding" process you have throughout the pipeline. But it would be best to setup YAML, because that dicatate what environment variables to be loaded - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/key-vault-in-own-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=portal

Comment: $env:variablename will get you the variable value.

Comment: @VasilNikolov I'm afraid even in YAML you need to explicitly specify map the secret to an env variable.

Comment: @DillyB and how could you make that call dynamic then. The name if my variable is in another string variable

Comment: @Sven Peeters, my bad. I wrongly understood the question. Since it is a classic pipe line, you can add one more task with az inline script with if condition - based on your environment get the secret and pass it to the next task

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom object with all pipeline fields needed for the cmdlet. Your cmdlet must use pipeline by property name so it is parsed out accordingly.

Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)

Comment: This moves the problem to the part where you create the custom object, or am I missing something here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parametersetmetadata.valuefrompipelinebypropertyname

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, the pipeline variables I'm refering to are variables defined on the DevOps build or release pipeline. Has nothing to do with pipe support.

Comment: @SvenPeeters you are correct that was a min understanding on my part. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I abondonned the "Azure Key Vault" task and just used an Azure Cli with "az keyvault".
Pretty easy to do in fact and you have full flexibility

(az keyvault secret show --name '$(SecretName)' --vault-name '$(KeyvaultName)' |ConvertFrom-Json).value